# BGI graphics for Linux?

Tags: c, linux, graphics, bgi

I need to know whether there is any BGI library for graphics in Linux.

Please do not suggest any library other than BGI because I want to use it using C and I am comfortable with it.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to use it using C and I am comfortable with it

Is that a reason to shun other, perhaps more suitable C accessible libraries that are fit-for-purpose?

A quick search online showed that:

1. BGI is abandoned
2. There is BOSS

I quote:

> BOSS
>
> This is the BGI Over SDL Subsystem
>   that consists of a rewrite of old DOS
>   header file/libraries:  Borland's
>   graphics.h, conio.h, bios.h.  Also
>   includes some support for sound and
>   for mouse.  I started this project to
>   support a couple DOS game projects a
>   friend and I were working on many
>   years ago.  Here's the page on which I
>   had charted my original progress.

Which [you can find here](http://www.codedread.com/boss.php)

Comment: Compatibility layers are the bomb. I have to agree with Aiden here though, starting new projects using obsolete interfaces is usually ill-advised.